# editing cells , excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

wonder if somebody could help,

cell B2 has a vlookup formula in it, I want to be able to type "Y" in C2 and the information displayed in B2 to be either colour blocked out or erased, keeping the formula in B2. when I remove the "Y" I would like the original information to be displayed in B2 again , is this possible ? failing this a check box in C2 maybe?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but you can just nest the VLOOKUP inside an IF

=IF(C2="Y", "", VLOOKUP(3, A1:A5, 1))

If true, show empty string, otherwise result from VLookup.

Comment: yes this has worked fine thankyou

Comment: Glad to hear it.  And welcome to Super User.  If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: hi just have a slight amendment to the above ,

Comment: rather than vlookup in cell B2 I have now decided to use a data validation drop down list , when "Y" is type into C2 I need B2 to clear then when the "Y" is removed I need the original information of the data validation to be displayed . any ideas how this could be done ?

Comment: Then I would use one of the other conditional formatting suggestions here to change the font color to hide it.  Or better, create a new question with exactly what you want since it looks like it's gone beyond your original request.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a formula inside conditional formatting that will allow you to change the background colour or grey out text depending on whether C2 has a "Y" in it.

e.g Locatate Conditional formatting tab = choose more rules = choose "use a formula to determine which cells to format" = inside formula section put "=$C$2="Y"", then choose the formatting options.

Answer (score 0):

If create a helper column in column A you can use conditional formatting.
1) Select the column which contains your data.
2) Click on the conditional formatting button and select "new rule".
3) Select to use a formula to format the cells and enter =$A1="Y" in the formula bar.
4) Click on the format button and select to fill your cells black.
This should block out the values if there is a Y in column A.

Comment: The question says the OP already wants to type "Y" in `C2`, so why are you telling him to enter "Y" in `A1`?